# Is it possible to create a telephone directory/provider directory kind of pdf report using SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I don't see repeater kind of insert-able object where I can create directory kind of report in SSRS. Any input on how to achieve this kind of reporting in SSRS?
Similar to a telephone directory like shown in figure[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and show a sample of your data plus a screen shot of what you expect the final output to look like.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have added the image.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken this sample data from the Adventure works sample database customer table.

I simply added a table and aded placeholders in the first cell for each of the customer elements I wants to display and formatted them as required.

Then in the report properties, I set the columns to 3.

The design looks like this...

[image]

Note that multi column layouts only work with certain renderers such as PDF so if I view it on screen I get this

[image]

If I export the report to a PDF I get this.

[image]

There are ways to get round doing it on screen to but that's more complicated. Let me know if you need to do this on screen too.

Comment: I tired doing the same but I am getting it in only 1 column and also I need table of content with page numbers and indexes with page number. Is this possible with SSRS?

Comment: Did you see the comment about this only working when you export. If you are only looking at the normal report interactive view it will show only 1 column. Once you get this working then I would start a new question regarding the index. Also, as I said in my answer, there are ways to get 3 columns on screen but it is more complicated.